# Will your private tabs still be open when you exit out of private mode?

Tags: safari

I don’t know what to do. I don’t want to exit out of my private mode without my open private tabs being deleted. Does anyone knows what happens, if you exit out off private mode and then go back to private mode, will they be still there?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about iOS, yes. Private tabs will be preserved.

In macOS, once you close the private tab(s), they are gone.

Comment: If you have Safari set to re-open tabs when you quit it, it will also re-open Private Mode tabs.

Comment: @At0mic Can you please edit that into the answer while explaining the context. Thanks.